# imshow() produces different output to imwrite()

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was wondering how it is possible to save an image created by imshow() in matlab. The code below uses the imshow() function with the min and max arguments specified - How can I apply this directly to the image itself instead of just specifying Matlab to *show* it?

```
imshow(img4fft, [1 300000]);
imwrite(img4fft, 'img.png');
```

Writing to the file produces a different output to what is shown via imshow().

Can anyone suggest how to get the output from imshow() saved as an image?

Many thanks MatLab is an alien language to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I obtain the same result by doing:

```
img4fft2=min(double(img4fft),300000)/300000;
imwrite(img4fft2,'img.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply saturation to the image manually:

```
I2 = imadjust(I, [0,30000],[0,2^{resolution}-1]);
imwrite('out.png', I2);
```

Comment: Im afraid that does not produce the same result so cannot be used!